# Agregar en carrito de compras productos usando checkbox

Tags: php5

esta pregunta es orientativa ya que no tengo idea de como encarar este pedido de un cliente.
Hice un carrito de compras tradicional con el botón agregar en cada cuota a pagar y ahora el cliente desea que se seleccionen las cuotas con un checkbox y que el botón agregar este al final del listado.
El código del listado es este, para que se orienten

```
<?php
if($num_rows1>1){
$queryy= "
SELECT * 
FROM 
deudas
WHERE
profe_deu=$dni AND anio_deu <= 2022
ORDER BY venc_deu Asc";
$sqly = mysql_query($queryy) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqly)) {
$x_id_deu = $row["id_deu"];
$x_cuota_deu = $row["nro_cuota"];
$x_anio_deu = $row["anio_deu"];
$x_venc_deu = FormatDateTime($row["venc_deu"],2);
$x_importe_deu = $row["importe_deu"];
$hoy = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:sO", strtotime('+7 days'));
$concepto = "Pago Cuota CIEC";
$ident = "0100";
$identi= "$x_id_deu";
$anito= "$x_anio_deu";
if($x_cuota_deu=='0'){
$prod = "CUOTA ANUAL - $x_anio_deu";    
}else{
$prod = "CUOTA $x_cuota_deu - $x_anio_deu"; 
}

echo "
<tr>\n";
if ($x_cuota_deu=='0') { 
echo "";
}else if ($x_cuota_deu >= '1'){
echo "
<th scope=\"row\">CUOTA- $x_cuota_deu</th>\n";
echo " 
<td>$x_anio_deu</td>
<td>$ $x_importe_deu</td>
<td>$x_venc_deu</td>
<td>
<form method=\"post\" action=\"\">
<input name=\"iddeuda\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"\n";
echo openssl_encrypt ($identi,COD,KEY);
echo"
     \"/>
     <input name=\"monto\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$x_importe_deu\"/>
     <input name=\"matricula\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"\n";
echo openssl_encrypt ($dni,COD,KEY);
echo"     
     \"/>
         <input name=\"conc\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"\n";
echo openssl_encrypt ($prod,COD,KEY);
echo"     
     \"/>
<input name=\"venc1\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"\n";
echo openssl_encrypt ($hoy,COD,KEY);
echo"     
     \"/>
<input name=\"concept_id\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"\n";
echo $concepto;
echo"     
     \"/>
    <input name=\"anito\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"\n";
echo $anito;
echo"     
     \"/>
     <input name=\"deb\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"cre\"/>
     <input value=\"Agregar\" type=\"submit\" class=\"submit\" name=\"btnAccion\"/>
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
\n";
}
}
?>
```

Alguna idea de como comenzar a buscar una solución para este pedio y que san google me largue algun ejemplo.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Te faltan muchas cosas para conseguirlo. Para empezar le falta el cierre al primer if. Luego tendrias que quitar todos los <form></form> para que solo quedara uno que empezara al principo de la tabla y con el cierre al final, con el boton de agregar. Luego agregar una columna nueva con el checkbox y usando el mismo name pero en forma de matriz, es decir, `name="reg[]"`. Luego, al darle al boton de submit, recoger ese array $_POST[reg] y recorrerla con un bucle e ir sacando los valores y aplicar el "agregar" que hacias hasta ahora individualmente, y yasta

Comment: Gracias masterguro, por contestarme, o sea que se puede, veré de buscar algún código para tenerlo de modelo, ya que soy nuevo en todo esto y no tengo mucho conocimiento de programación, todo lo hago a pulmón. Un Abrazo

Comment: si encuentran por ahi algo, me avisan, hasta ahora nada